How to achieve the linear convolution of a 100 sample time series and a 20 tap filter in the frequency domain?
I'm doing my bachelor's right now. I have learned continuous and discreet convolutions, so I feel like I should know how to answer this question. But I'm not sure how to go about it. I came across this question on an internship application btw.
I have never heard of "20 tap filter".is that just a FIR filter with 20 coefficients?
**
Here's my attempt:
**
If I was to use something like Matlab, I  would let t= 100 time series and h = 20 tap filter transfer function.Then zero pad both to the correct length to prevent circular convolution.  Correct length= (length of x) + (length of h)-1.
Then, Linear convolution= invFFT[FFT{t} * FFT{h)]
Is that a good and proper answer?
Thank you for any help/feedback!

I think given that this question is focused on DSP and not on programming, it is better asked at DSP stack exchange. Whenever you are having some problems with implementing what you learnt there, come back. Though please read the how to ask a good question first. Best of luck on your BT!

you do seem to understand the relationship between convolution and fourier transform. what are you majoring in?

@ChristophRackwitz Yeah, I believe I do understand the relationship between convolution and Fourier transform. I'm majoring in Electrical Engineering.
